# Delete windows profiles with similar names using a batch file or script

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, user-management, batch-file

I’m on a Windows 2008 server and would like to delete 15 users (user1 till user15) without having to do this by hand.

After deleting them completely I’d like to readd them (again, with a script) and give all of them the same password for which the script should ask for.

Any help (hints, complete script) is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "net user" command to add and delete accounts.

Here is a generic batch file that will LOOP:

```
@echo off

set i=%1
set j=%2
if NOT DEFINED i goto USAGE
if NOT DEFINED j goto USAGE

set /a j = %i% + %2

@echo start, i = %I% and j = %J%

:LOOP
if %i% GTR %j% goto FINISHED
echo i = %i%
set /a i=%i + 1
goto LOOP

:FINISHED
@echo.
@echo finished, i = %I%
@echo.
goto END

:USAGE
@echo.
@echo Usage   : loop.bat [ start # ] [ # of iterations ]
@echo Example : loop.bat 4 5   (this will start at 4 and end at 9)
@echo.
goto END

:END
@echo.
```

In the loop you would need to do two things:

- net user /delete user%I%
- net user /add user%I% (with more options)

You can modifiy the batch file to take a third argument which could be the password that is then passed on to the "net user /add" command.

Use "net help user" to get more information on how to use the command.

Comment: Wow, that was fast :-).

Will try in a few minutes. Thanks so much.